# Ubuntu wakes up on it's own

Tags: suspend, 22.04

My new laptop (Lenovo X1 Gen 10) wakes up quite often from sleep without any visible reason. The previous Laptop (Lenovo T490) didn't do that with exactly the same setup and external devices. Is there a command or log file that could help me find the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Does that happen if you move an external mouse?

Comment: /var/log/syslog

Comment: `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` shortly after waking.